# Inputmask - Regex currency and optional decimal places

Tags: regex, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to create a currency Regex using the Robin Herbots Inputmask plugin and can't find a way to make it all work together
I need a regex that allows precision from 2 to 10 digits and adds a comma on the thousands, like these:

1,123.00

123.12345

1,123,456.1234567890

and so on. I ended up with these regexes `^\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*$` and `\d{1,99},\d{2,10}`. They both achieve what I need, but separately. How to I make them both work together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^(?=(?:,?\d){1,99}(?:\.|$))\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2,10})?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ee4PQu/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:,?\d){1,99}(?:\.|$))` - a positive lookahead that requires 1 to 99 occurrences of an optional `,` followed with a digit, and then followed with either `.` or end of string
- `\d{1,3}` - one to three digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - zero or more occurrences of a comma and then three digits
- `(?:\.\d{2,10})?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and two to ten digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks for the response! this seems to be on point in regex101 but if I try it with the inputmask plugin, it doesnt seem to work.. https://jsfiddle.net/xslok/94wh5jxu/7/ do you have any idea why?

Comment: @xSlok That means you cannot use a pure regex solution.

Comment: I see... the regex is really a solution to another need I have. The regular currency mask works nice for this, but I need optional decimal places from 2 to 10